# Can you help me with my first crash report of type NO_CRASH_STACK?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, crash-reports

For the first time ever I discovered on App Store Connect that one of my apps had a number (19 to be precise) on the `crashes` column. So, I opened `Window > Organizer` and then I found out that there was indeed a crash report.

On the left column of the Organizer I have: `AppName: NO_CRASH_STACK (2 devices)`. And on the middle one I have this below:

```
Thread 0

0   dyld   __abort_with_payload
1   dyld   abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal
2   dyld   abort_with_payload
3   dyld   dyld4::halt(char const*)
4   dyld   dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)
5   dyld   start
```

This wasn't very clear so I opened it on the Finder, and here's the interesting part I guess:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: DYLD 4 Symbol missing
Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation26MeasurementFormatUnitUsageVAASo14NSUnitPressureCRszrlE10barometricACyAEGvgZ
Referenced from: /Volumes/VOLUME/*/AppName.app/AppName
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
```

I'm not sure but I think that the error could come from this line of my code:

```
Text(currentWeather.pressure.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .barometric)))
```

And my guess is that in some regions/countries, this line wants to show an amount with a symbol that doesn't exit in some iOS versions so the app crashes.

Do you think I'm correct?

Comment: Why do you think that line is at fault?

Comment: @jnpdx Because I have only one line that shows a `pressure`.